# Python Flask SQLAlchemy - display data from related model in jinja2 template

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hoping someone out there can help.

I have a Flask application which contains a list of individuals.  Each individual has a birth location and a death location and the locations are stored in a separate table.

When I display the details of the individuals in my jinja template, I want to show the individual's details like name, date of birth, date of death etc along with the details of the location for those events.

There are plenty of answers on SO which talk about backrefs etc but I'm not sure how I'd use these if a location could be someone's birth location, death location etc.

Here's the simplified code: -

```
class Individual(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "individual"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    forenames = db.Column(db.Text)
    surname = db.Column(db.Text)
    fullname = db.Column(db.Text)
    gender = db.Column(db.Text)
    dob = db.Column(db.Date)
    birth_location = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"))
    dod = db.Column(db.Date)
    death_location = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Individual, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "location"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.Text)
    parish = db.Column(db.Text)
    district = db.Column(db.Text)
    townorcity = db.Column(db.Text)
    county = db.Column(db.Text)
    country = db.Column(db.Text)
    short_location = db.Column(db.Text)       # A short version of the full location
    full_location = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Location, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.full_location
```

In my template, I currently have:

```
{{ person.birth_location }}
```

... but this, understandably, just outputs the ID of the location.

If I try

```
{{ father.birth_location.short_location }}
```

...then it just gives me a blank output.

Plenty of SO answers seem to suggest I need a relationship and backref somewhere in the location table but a location could be a birth location, death location, residence location etc - it's not just one thing which I can tie to a single backref.

All of the data saves fine in SQLAlchemy, it's just the output to the jinja template I'm struggling with.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious and the SQLAlchemy docs don't seem to address a similar scenario.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "...the SQLAlchemy docs don't seem to address a similar scenario." See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#basic-relationship-patterns Basic Relationship Patterns.

Comment: I read that, I'm asking for help in relation to this scenario.  I don't know how I can apply that to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following relationships to you `Individual` model:

```
class Individual(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "individual"

    ...

    birth_location_rel = relationship("Location", foreign_keys="[individual.birth_location]")
    death_location_rel = relationship("Location", foreign_keys="[individual.death_location]")
```

Then in the template you can use, and it should work:

```
{{ father.birth_location_rel.short_location }}
```

*In your case you do not really need a `backref`.*

---

Few more pointers:

- you get just "blank output" currently most likely because the configuration of flask/jinja2 is to ignore errors
- I would rename the column `birth_location` to `birth_location_id` and the newly introduced relationship to `birth_location` (same for "death"). This is a better naming (_id for column, proper name for relationship). Update the template accordingly.
- Finally, if the locations are not loaded in memory when the template is rendered, there might be queries going to the database for every individual to fetch those relationships. Depending on the number of such individuals displayed, this might lead to not optimal performance. If you get there, consider reading [Eager Loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading) section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the helpful response, @van.  Making your suggested changes result in an AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'birth_location'.  Any ideas whether I've missed a step?  I haven't done any of the recommended naming changes yet but I will once I can get this working.  Thanks again.

Comment: Fixed it - correct code added.  Thanks very much to @van.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @van, correct code replayed here: -

```
class Individual(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "individual"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    forenames = db.Column(db.Text)
    surname = db.Column(db.Text)
    fullname = db.Column(db.Text)
    gender = db.Column(db.Text)
    dob = db.Column(db.Date)
    birth_location = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"))
    birth_location_rel = relationship("Location", foreign_keys="[Individual.birth_location]")   
    dod = db.Column(db.Date)
    death_location = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"))
    death_location_rel = relationship("Location", foreign_keys="[Individual.death_location]")     
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Individual, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Location(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "location"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.Text)
    parish = db.Column(db.Text)
    district = db.Column(db.Text)
    townorcity = db.Column(db.Text)
    county = db.Column(db.Text)
    country = db.Column(db.Text)
    short_location = db.Column(db.Text)
    full_location = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Location, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
```

The data can then be displayed in the jinja template as @van suggested -

`{{ father.birth_location_rel.short_location }}`